# Devise define routes and before_filter for users with admin attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have an small app where I implemented devise. The model where I added Devise is `consultant` instead of `user`.

```
class Consultant < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  def admin?
    self.admin == true
  end

end
```

I also added an attribute like it suggest [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role) the option 2 to identify admin users.

My goal is to achieve that only admin consultants have access everywhere. Consultants that are not admins should only have access to `resources :tasks` and `get   '/tasks/consultants/:id/worked', to: 'tasks#worked'`. Visitors should be redirected to the sign_in.

For that purpose I am adding a `before_filter` in `ApplicationController` like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :authenticate_admin!
  skip_before_filter :authenticate_admin!, only: [:tasks]

  private
  def authenticate_admin!
    current_consultant.try(:admin?)
  end

end
```

and in `tasks_controller.rb` I added this `before_filter`

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_filter :authenticate_consultant!

  ...
```

and my `routes.rb` is defined like this

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :consultants
  devise_scope :consultant do
    authenticated :consultant do
      root 'tasks#index'
    end

    root to: "devise/sessions#new"
  end

  get '/home', to: 'static_pages#home'
  get '/help', to: 'static_pages#help'

  get   '/tasks/consultants/:id/worked', to: 'tasks#worked'

  resources :tasks
  resources :consultants

end
```

I don't understand why is not validating the users, any user can access anywhere

---

**Update 1**

just an small note, I changed every `before_filter` for `before_action` because `before_filter` is deprecated

As @Raffael suggested I updated my `application_controller.rb` as

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :authenticate_admin!

  def authenticate_admin!
    unless current_consultant.try(:admin?)
      flash[:error] = 'Shoo, this is not for you'
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

end
```

But I get an error

> localhost redirected you too many times.

I think this is happening because I am redirecting from `routes.rb` and `application_controller.rb`. When it tries to access `devise/sessions#new` needs to be authenticaded.

I tried to avoid this by adding the following to the before_action in the `application_controller.rb`

```
before_action :authenticate_admin!, :except => ['devise/sessions#new']
```

---

**Update 2: Solution**

Finally this is what I have done, first I created a new file called `admin_controller.rb`

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_admin!

  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def authenticate_admin!
    unless current_consultant.try(:admin?)
      flash[:error] = 'Shoo, this is not for you'
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

end
```

Second for controllers that need admin privileges I extend from the new class like this

```
class AnyController < AdminController
```

The `application_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :authenticate_consultant!, :except => ['devise/sessions#new']

  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

end
```

and in `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :consultants

  root to: 'tasks#index'
...
```

Is not an elegant solution, but it works. for example it would be better to have all the admin controllers in its own namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a falsey value form a filter won't halt the filter chain any more (it did in previous versions of Rails).

If you want your `before_filter` to prevent the controller action from being executed, you need to redirect or render.

For example something along the lines of:

```
def authenticate_admin!
  unless current_consultant.try(:admin?)
    flash[:error] = 'Shoo, this is not for you'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

or:

```
def authenticate_admin!
  unless current_consultant.try(:admin?)
    flash[:error] = 'You need to be logged in as an admin to use this resource'
    render 'login_dialog'
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Raffael, that helped me but now I am facing a new problem I will update the question

Comment: Well, endless redirection is a couple too many :) – You can solve this by modifying the filter line like so: `before_action :authenticate_admin!,
unless: :devise_controller?`

Comment: thank you @Raffael, your answer give me the key for the solution, I will post it on the question